# Can't see the complete statistics on info panel

Tags: interface

Here's the screenshot of my blender.

[image]

Some words and numbers are only shown like "...", so I can't see correct numbers of statistics .

Can anyone help me to solve this problem, please?
Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce thus, how did that occur? What happens if your stretch the window?

Comment: I'm sorry but...I have no idea. It has been like this already when I open Blender. [Another Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/0dCVkrV.jpg)